# Closing Browser window after using function to open it

Tags: c#

I'm trying to open a chrome window, allow enough time for a clip from YouTube to be played, then close the chrome window, all in C#. I'm relatively new to coding and I'm at a loss.

```
 public static void OpenWebsite(string URL)
    {
        Process p1 = new Process();
        p1.StartInfo.FileName = "chrome.exe";
        p1.StartInfo.Arguments = URL;
        p1.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
        p1.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(7000);
    }
```

What can I add after the Thread.Sleep to close the browser window without closing the program?

Comment: p1.Kill()   ... https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/50ecbcf2-d2d3-4f21-9775-5b8be1bd4346/how-to-terminate-a-process-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @OldProgrammer : Why are you linking him to a forum thread which lacks information about the method, rather than linking him to [**the documentation**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

```
p1.CloseMainWindow();
p1.Close();
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.close(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: **IMPORTANT NOTE:** `Process.Close()` _**does not**_ affect the process itself, it just releases the memory of the `Process` class instance in your application.